# KOMA: set the chapter title on its own page, moving the text to a new page

Tags: chapters, koma-script

I'm using the KOMA `scrbook` class and I'd like to have the chapter title on an otherwise blank page. The actual text in the chapter should move to the next page. Is there a way to insert a `\clearpage` after the chapter number and title are typeset?

The main reason for this is that I would like to add a background image to the chapter title page using the functionality of the `scrlayer-scrpage` package.

I tried using `\RedeclareSectionCommand` and adding extra space like I did below, but if I set `afterskip` to `\textheight` the title also moves to the next page. Alternatively, is there a way to execute a command (e.g. `\clearpage` right after `\chapter` is run? Or should I manually add a `\clearpage` after each call to `\chapter` in my document (but that won't work for the table of contents, for example)?

An MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=0pt,
  afterskip=0.9\textheight, % skip between the chapter position and the normal text
]{chapter}


\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

which results in the following (note the start of the regular chapter text at the bottom of the page:

[image: Almost there, but not quite]

Comment: My guts tell me `\renewcommand{\chapterendvskip}{\clearpage}` but i didn't test it yet. EDIT: Works fine, good MWE :-)

Comment: That should be `\chapterheadendvskip`, I guess :-). Thanks! Works like a charm. If you write it down as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument for `afterskip` should be a length, but a more appropriate `\clearpage` is needed. KOMA also provides `\cheapterheadendvskip` to add something after the chapter title, which must not be a length, but can be some arbitrary code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    beforeskip=0pt,
%   afterskip=0.9\textheight, % skip between the chapter position and the normal text
]{chapter}
\renewcommand{\chapterheadendvskip}{\clearpage}% <-


\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```